# working with res.render, ejs and Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, single-page-application

I’m building a dashboard style application with Node.js, Express, and Angular.js. I have a simple login/registration to get to a dashboard view which is an angular single page application. OK, I’m trying to pass data from my routes.js file to my SPA. As of right now I can get this data on my dashboard.html page with no issues using ejs. However that data is not available in the partials (html files) that my angular SPA is displaying. How would I make this data available to the entire SPA and not just the dashboard.html? Is this even possible using ejs? Should I be taking another approach from getting user data from the routes.js to the SPA? any help is greatly appricaited, Thanks!

```
### App Structure ###
— client
    index.html
    — static
        dashboard.html
        — css
        — js
        — imgs
        — partials
            home.html
            profile.html
— config
    routes.js
— node_modules
package.json
server.js


/** in routes.js **/
  app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {

    res.render('./static/dashboard.html', {
      user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });

  }


<!—- dashboard.html -—>

    <p> <%= user.username %> </p>
    ###result -> 'kobe@aol.com'

<-- partials/home.html -->

    <p> <%= user.username %> </p>
    ###result -> '<%= user.username %>'
```

Comment: unless you have no choice, you shouldn't render data server side with EJS when using a SPA framework like angular.  instead, set up API endpoints to send your data as JSON, and do all your rendering through the client side.  (i.e. use `{{user.username}}` instead of `<%= user.username %>`).

Comment: @Claies, you're exactly right. And I already knew this but needed someone to re-phrase it just as you did. I built a user factory and controller and set up an API endpoint to get the user from the req.user object. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.